# Visual Studio Code - How to delete spaces until next word

Tags: visual-studio-code

Looking for a key combination in Visual Studio Code (VS Code) to delete all the spaces/whitespace from the cursor until the next character/word.

For example:

```
first words in sentence          _               last words in sentence
```

If my cursor is at the underscore, with a single key combination I would like to delete all the spaces between the cursor and 'last'.

Bonus points for another key combination that will delete all spaces between the cursor and the 'e' in 'sentence'.

A single key combination that deletes all spaces around the cursor is less appealing, but acceptable.

Visual Studio Code 1.63.2 (Universal)
MacOS: 12.1

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the keyboard shortcuts and searching for 'deleteword' brought up a lot of word-deletion commands that are not mapped to keys but did not turn up in my internet searches.

I found the command `deleteWordPartLeft` served my purpose and I have mapped it to an unused key combination.

There are several other options, such as `deleteWordPartLeft/deleteWordPartRight`, `deleteWordStartLeft/deleteWordStartRight`, `deleteWordEndLeft/deleteWordEndRight`, and `deleteWordLeft/deleteWordRight` which might better fit your needs.